# Data Binding to a property inside a self-made class

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I am currently learning a Little bit about WPF but I am failing to understand DataBindings. I've tried many Solutions I found on StackOverflow and on MSDN but None will do what I want them to.

I have the following construct:

C#-Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestDataBindings
{
    internal class TextStore
    {
        internal ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; set; }
        internal string Text { get; set; }

        internal TextStore()
        {
            this.Text = "Hello World!!!!";
            this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<string> { "hello", "World", "!!!!" };
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataBindings.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataBindings"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextStore x:Key="TextStorage"></local:TextStore>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="160,108,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource TextStorage}, Path=Text}"/>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="305,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TextStorage}, Path=Collection}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now I would expect Hello World!!!! to appear inside my TextBox and the three strings to Pop into my ListBox but neither of those things happen. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can only bind to public properties.  Try changing from internal to public.  The class and constructor can still be internal.

Comment: Thank you very much, you just solved a huge slew of problems at once. Is there any documentation that would tell you that you can only bind to public properties? I have been reading a lot of tutorials in search for a clue but I never found that you could only bind onto public properties. Thhank you so much.

Comment: [Heres some](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#binding_sources).  Also, the output window will typically help get you started on tracking down issues.  It has saved me a large number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to set the DataConetxt of your MainWindow using an instance of the TextStore Class:

```
var textStore = new TextStore();
this.DataContext = textStore;
```

then in order for the Ui to be notified for the changed that had been done to the properties they are bound to, you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface, and you need to call the OnpropertyChanged Method in each property setter:

```
 internal class TextStore : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _collection;
    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
    {
        get
        {
            return _collection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_collection == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _collection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_text == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    internal TextStore()
    {
        this.Text = "Hello World!!!!";
        this.Collection = new ObservableCollection<string> { "hello", "World", "!!!!" };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: The Problem was actually the internal keyword, I changed it to public and the binding worked without any Problems. I do know how to implement the PropertyChanged Event when I want to actually cmmunicate changes to the GUI, but thank you anyway.